# Showing labels on bubble chart in angular-charts

Tags: chart.js, bubble-chart, angular-chart

I am using bubble charts in angular-charts (its based on charts.js)

Users have to hover on bubbles to know their labels

How can I either show labels or turn on tooltips permanently in bubble chart

Premraj

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify it within the options of Chartjs, specifically the callback part. I've given an example of what that looks like. [Chart JS Documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-tooltip-callbacks)

```
    vm.options = {
    "callbacks": {
        "label": function (tooltipItem, data) {
          return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks @Sai . I had moved on with this issue. I will confirm if solution is working and accept answer. Thanks for your time